# getting data from express server with angular 2

Tags: javascript, express, angular

I'm trying to build a small facebook login with angular 2 but well I'm having problem, after logging in the facebook the user would be redirected to /home

```
app.get('/home', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname, '../', 'views', 'index.html'), { user: req.user});
    console.log({ user: req.user});
});
```

I'm trying to display the user information in angular2 page but I keep getting undefined. console logging the object works fine.

I used the same method with ejs files using res.render 
and using this inside the ejs

```
<%= user.facebook.name %>
```

and it works fine. I tried to use {{}} in the angular 2 but not working.
any help please?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would define this element when bootstrapping your application. Because this hint is only available within your `index.html` page, I would use the following processing.

Update the file that bootstraps your application:

```
import {bootstrap} from '...';
import {provide} from '...';
import {AppComponent} from '...';

export function main(facebookUser) {
  bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    provide('user', { useValue: facebookUser })
  ]);
}
```

Provide this value from the `index.html` file this way:

```
<script>
  var facebookUser = '<%= user.facebook.name %>';
  System.import('app/main').then((module) => {
    module.main(facebookUser);
  });
</script>
```

This question could interest you:

- [Pass Constant Values to Angular from _layout.cshtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312018/pass-constant-values-to-angular-2-from-layout-cshtml/37384567#37384567)

Answer (score 0):

ok thanks for the replies i found the answer for my question. this code will call the api that and get the user details

```
constructor(private http: Http) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.getUser();
}

getUser() {
    this.http.get('/api/user')
        .map((res:Response) => res.json())
        .do(data => console.log('data: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
        .subscribe(
            data => { this.user = data.user.facebook.name},
            err => console.error(err),
            () => console.log('done')
        );

}
```